# Fetch data from core data having relationships among entities

Tags: ios, database, core-data, relational-database

In my core data model, I have 2 entity like department and employee,
dept entity has two attributes (deptId and deptName) and employee entity has 4 attributes (empId,empName,empAge,deptId). One dept may have n numbers of employees so the relationship is 1 to many.

Now I need to fetch data from employee table, like fetch all employee details who's department is "HR". So what will be my query to core data to fetch desired results?

Answer (score 0):

while creating the relationship between two entities,I think you have given relation ship name by using that name we can get objects.

-(void)getEmployeeListFromDB
{

```
arrEmpList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrEmpList = [(NSMutableArray *)[deptIdObj.relationshipFromDeptToEmployes allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

}